# render partial is generating an undefined variable for object in hartl tutorial chapter 10

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, railstutorial.org

Maybe I've been staring at the code for too long and need a fresh pair of eyes but This has me stumped.I have a failing test telling me :

```
undefined local variable or method `object'


1) User pages edit with invalid information 
     Failure/Error: visit edit_user_path(user)
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `object' for #<#<Class:0x007fdfb561ae80>:0x007fdfb58ab500>
     # ./app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__error_messages_html_erb__4119139248776046323_70299400131820'
     # ./app/views/users/edit.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_users_edit_html_erb___2909598206032311320_70299400097640'
     # ./app/views/users/edit.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users_edit_html_erb___2909598206032311320_70299400097640'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:116:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

** UPDATE : I solved this one and posted my fields so that people with the same issue can observe work it out. There is a lot that can be said from staring at something for too long. IF you get frustrated, take a walk or something, you'll probably notice the error was obvious to fix just from taking a fresh look after a break as was the case with mine. Check for duplication and call object: @user for your field partial while calling f: f for your renders. that will clear it up :)

users_controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Tweeter App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted."
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation)
  end

  # Before filters

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

user_pages_spec :

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "index" do
    before do
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Bob", email: "bob@example.com")
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Ben", email: "ben@example.com")
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_title('All users') }
    it { should have_content('All users') }

    it "should list each user" do
      User.all.each do |user|
        expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name)
      end
    end

    describe "pagination" do

      before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
      after(:all)  { User.delete_all }

      it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

      it "should list each user" do
        User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
          expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name)
        end
      end
    end

    describe "delete links" do

      it { should_not have_link('delete') }

      describe "as an admin user" do
        let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
        before do
          sign_in admin
          visit users_path
        end

        it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
        it "should be able to delete another user" do
          expect do
            click_link('delete', match: :first)
          end.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
        end
        it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let!(:m1) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Foo") }
    let!(:m2) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Bar") }

    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }

    describe "microposts" do
      it { should have_content(m1.content) }
      it { should have_content(m2.content) }
      it { should have_content(user.microposts.count) }
    end
  end

    describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }

        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
        it { should have_title(user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user
      visit edit_user_path(user)
    end

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
      it { should have_title("Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
      let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
      before do
        fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
        fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
        fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password

        click_button "Save changes"
      end

      it { should have_title(new_name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      specify { expect(user.reload.name).to  eq new_name }
      specify { expect(user.reload.email).to eq new_email }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my index view :

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

Here is my edit view :

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'users/fields', f: f %>
      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails">change</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my new view :

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'users/fields', f: f %>
      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my field partial :

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>

<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password %>

<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
```

Here is my error message partial :

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post the view as well?  I'm not sure which view it is based on the above, but it sounds like the `index` view.

Comment: about `Unable to find field "Name"` - I suggest to install gem `launchy` and call method `save_and_open_page` before calling `fill_in "Name"` - this will create a screenshot and you can see the same picture as Capybara sees. About `param not found: user` - I can suggest to open `test.log` and see what params comes to controller (or you can use `binding.pry` in controller to check `params`). PS I do not see evident mistakes

Comment: I added my index, new, and edit views.

Comment: I'll add the launchy gem and give it a go. Thanks for that tip

Comment: it seems that @CDub was right - the problem in views. If you want to create (signup) user you should give him an opportunity to fill in fields: Name, Email, Passowrd. You should add on the views `f.text_field :name` `f.password_field :password` etc.

Comment: Right on. I have a fields partial with those fields included (I updated my post to reflect so I don't think that is the problem. Could it be capitalization?

Comment: lets solve one problem (for example `Unable to find field "Name"`). Does it work if you sign_up manually (I mean just in development ENV)? Did `save_and_open_page` show a form with all needed fields?

Comment: Ok, so the `new#user` was missing a field partial. I added one : `<%= render 'layouts/fields', object: f.object %>` . However, when I try to signup, it says `undefined local variable or method `object'`

Comment: you should `render 'layouts/fields', f: f`

Comment: I made the changes in the renders. Now rspec is telling me `undefined local variable or method `object'` All of the failing tests say the same thing that `object` is `undefined`

Comment: Is it right that you have `<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>` at the top of your shared/error_messages partial?  That looks like it will immediately cause issues.  That is to say, you're calling `shared/error_messages` twice.  Once with object: f.object and once without.  You should take it out of the partial, or in the partial, call it like you're calling it in the form.

Comment: I don't have `<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>` at the top of my shared/error_messages partial. I do have it on the top of my fields partial though.

Comment: right.  you need to pass object: object for both cases where you've called the shared/error_messages.  or just call it in one place.  I guess I don't see where the field partial is getting pulled in.  In your "my new view" you call shared/error messages and then a submit button.  Then in your "fields" partial, it's there at the top.  Maybe this is a cut/paste issue?

Comment: Thats what I get for staring at my code for way too many hours. There is a lot to be said for taking a break. I ended up fixing it by using `f: f` in the renders for edit and new. For the `error_message` partial itself, I used `object: @user`. That made my tests pass. Any duplication was simply from me going back and forth so many times making changes. I went through systematically and dried it up. Thanks for the assist! I appreciate it!

Comment: nice.  more than 2 eyeballs on a project can be a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** UPDATE : I solved this one and posted my fields so that people with the same issue can observe work it out. There is a lot that can be said from staring at something for too long. IF you get frustrated, take a walk or something, you'll probably notice the error was obvious to fix just from taking a fresh look after a break as was the case with mine. Check for duplication and call object: @user for your field partial while calling f: f for your renders. that will clear it up :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line of fields partial layout file(_fields.html.erb) to:
      **<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>**
solved my similar problem.